# What characters will never be in a tomcat/spring boot session id?

Tags: java, spring, tomcat

In a Spring Boot app, I want to pass a combined variable from one REST service, out through the user interface, and then back through a second REST service.  To accomplish this, I want the first REST service to create one single string by concatenating the session id with a different string representing something else, and with a separator value marking the break between the two strings, so that `String combined = sessionid+separatorcharacter+someotherstring`.  To do this, the second REST service will accept the combined string as an `@RequestParam`, and then decompose the string into the session id and the other value.

I will use `String.split()` to split the two parts of the combined string using a separator value, like:

```
String[] parts = string.split("separatorcharacter");
String sessionid = parts[0];
String someotherstring = parts[1];
```

But **what characters can I choose from when creating the marker separating the two parts of the string?**  The combined string will be used as a URL parameter, so it has to be able to cross the internet in `http` requests and also never be present in any session id produced by Spring or tomcat.  Also, one of the strings is going to be Base64 encoded, so the separator character needs to survive the encode/decode process.  **I will decode before splitting, so we don't need to worry about the characters used while encoded.**

But, in case it matters, the encode/decode is:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;

import sun.misc.BASE64Decoder;
import sun.misc.BASE64Encoder;

public class StringUtil {

    private static Random random = new Random((new Date()).getTime());

    public static String encrypt(String userId) {  
        BASE64Encoder encoder = new BASE64Encoder();
        byte[] salt = new byte[8];
        random.nextBytes(salt);
        return encoder.encode(salt)+encoder.encode(userId.getBytes());
    }

    public static String decrypt(String encryptKey) {
        if (encryptKey.length() > 12) {
            String cipher = encryptKey.substring(12);
            BASE64Decoder decoder = new BASE64Decoder();
            try {
                return new String(decoder.decodeBuffer(cipher));
            } catch (IOException e) {}
        }         
    return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: *Also, one of the strings is going to be Base64 encoded, so the separator character needs to survive the encode/decode process.* Base64 both `String`(s), and then use any other character?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I thought of that, but then I have to split them at some point, so the problem remains.  If I combine them then encode, then I have to decode the combination and split it into parts.  I need to avoid multiple `@RequestParam`s.

Comment: Even if you analysed the spring boot session generation code today, they might change it tomorrow. Why do you need to avoid multiple RequestParams?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch The session ids are all caps and numbers.  But I do not want to resort to just making something uo like using `__` as the separator without asking.  This question is emerging because adding a second parameter broke a program I am working on, and I think it is easiest just to always use simple code.  Plus, encoding things often adds characters, so two encoded parameters makes a huge url string, while combining two before encoding would result in a shorter url string.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch The purpose is to validate email addresses of new users who try to register for a web site.  The prototype had been sending them their session id in a hyperlink via email, but that breaks when a user tries to register multiple times with multiple different email addresses during the same session.  So I thought to concatenate the userid or email address to the sessionid.  Do you have a better idea?  This moment I am thinking of creating a GUID and sending that by email instead of the session id.